# Is there a way to update Linked Objects values in Docs? Basically update from Docs -> Sheets rather than only from Sheets -> Docs?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

Basically I have a table I have linked in Docs and I want the syncing to go both ways. Currently, I can only update the values in Sheets. If I update the values in Docs, the changes do not go into Sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the option to sync changes in linked tables from Google Docs to Google Sheets is currently not a feature.

Based on this [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7009814#zippy=%2Cedit-a-chart-table-or-slide) to edit a chart, table, or slide you need to do it through the source.

> On your computer, open a document or presentation in Google Docs or Google Slides.
> Click a chart or table to select it.
> In the top right corner of the chart or table, click Link options Down arrow and then Open source.
> You can now change the original file.

To request this feature to be available in Google Docs, go to a Google Doc, click on ‘Help’ > ‘Help Docs improve’ and give a description of your request.